# Apply rotation matrix to vector + plot it

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, vector, rotational-matrices

I have created a vector (v) and would like to perform the rotMatrix function on it. I cannot figure out how to call the function rotMatrix with a degree of 30 on the vector (v). I am also plotting the vectors.

Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
sns.set_style("white")
import math

def rotMatrix(angle):
    return np.array([[np.cos(np.degrees(angle)), np.arcsin(np.degrees(angle))], [np.sin(np.degrees(angle)), np.cos(np.degrees(angle))]])

v = np.array([3,7])
v30 = rotMatrix(np.degrees(30)).dot(v)

plt.arrow(0,0,v[0],v[1], head_width=0.8, head_length=0.8)
plt.arrow(0,0,v30[0],v30[1],head_width=0.8, head_length=0.8)
plt.axis([-5,5,0,10])
plt.show()
```

Comment: Have you explored `np.cos(...)` to see what kinds of input it takes?  Radians, degrees, etc?

Comment: try `v30 = rotMatrix(np.degrees(30)) * v` to multiply vector by rotation matrix. btw, degrees is for converting from radians to degrees so you don't pass it an angle in degrees

Comment: @hpaulj np.cos() takes radians which is why I used np.degrees. Is this incorrect?

Comment: @samgak I just tried that, no luck.

Comment: you need to use radians(30) to convert from degrees to radians

Comment: @samgak I am unsure what you mean. Are you able to show me the corrected code? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your rotMatrix function you have used the arcsin() function. You want to use -sin() You should also convert your degrees value to radians

```
return np.array([[np.cos(np.radians(angle)), 
                       -np.sin(np.radians(angle))],
                 [np.sin(np.radians(angle)),
                        np.cos(np.radians(angle))]])
```

Or slightly improve efficiently and readability by

```
c = np.cos(np.radians(angle))
s = np.sin(np.radians(angle))
return np.array([[c, -s], [s, c]])
```

and the call with

```
rotMatrix(30).dot(v)
```

-sin and arcsin are very different.

Comment: Thanks James! If I want to rotate it 30 degrees counter clockwise would I simply put -30 as the angle?

Comment: Yes, a negative angle should represent an anticlockwise rotation.

Answer (score 0):

When in doubt, play around with the calculations in an interactive Python/numpy session.

```
In [23]: 30/180*np.pi       # do it yourself convsion - easy
Out[23]: 0.5235987755982988
In [24]: np.radians(30)     # degrees to radians - samething
Out[24]: 0.52359877559829882
In [25]: np.sin(np.radians(30))    # sin(30deg)
Out[25]: 0.49999999999999994
```

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IlWnX.png)    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

```
A = np.array([[3],[-3]])

n = np.linspace(0,2*np.pi,100)

def rotate_me(A,n):
  fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols = 2, figsize=(18, 16))

  buf1 = []
  buf11 = []
  buf12 = []
  buf13 = []
  buf1p = []
  buf2 = []
#   t = []

  for theta in n:

    x=2
    x1=3
    x2=2
    x3=3
#     xp=3
#     theta = 1/p
    origin = [0],[0]
    R = np.array([[x*np.cos(theta),-np.sin(theta)],
                 [np.sin(theta),np.cos(theta)]])
    R1 = np.array([[np.cos(theta),-np.sin(theta)],
             [np.sin(theta),np.cos(theta)*x1]])
    R2 = np.array([[np.cos(theta),-np.sin(theta)],
             [x2*np.sin(theta),np.cos(theta)]])
    R3 = np.array([[np.cos(theta),-np.sin(theta)*x3],
             [np.sin(theta),np.cos(theta)]])
    Rp = np.array([[np.cos(theta),-np.sin(theta)],
             [np.sin(theta),np.cos(theta)]])

    V = R.dot(A)
    V1 = R1.dot(A)
    V2 = R2.dot(A)
    V3 = R3.dot(A)
    Vp = Rp.dot(A)

    buf1.append(np.linalg.norm(V))
    buf11.append(np.linalg.norm(V1))
    buf12.append(np.linalg.norm(V2))
    buf13.append(np.linalg.norm(V3))
    buf1p.append(np.linalg.norm(Vp))
#     buf2.append(np.linalg.norm(A))

    ax1.quiver(*origin,V[0,:],V[1,:], scale=21,color ='r',label='cos')
    ax1.quiver(*origin,V1[0,:],V1[1,:], scale=21,color ='g',label='cos')
    ax1.quiver(*origin,V2[0,:],V2[1,:], scale=21,color ='m',label='sin')
    ax1.quiver(*origin,V3[0,:],V3[1,:], scale=21,color ='b',label='-sin')
    ax1.quiver(*origin,Vp[0,:],Vp[1,:], scale=21,color ='k',label='pure')
#     print(theta)
#     ax1.legend()
  ax2.plot(n,buf1,color ='r')
  ax2.plot(n,buf11,color ='g')
  ax2.plot(n,buf12,color ='m')
  ax2.plot(n,buf13,color ='b')
  ax2.plot(n,buf1p,color ='k')
#   ax2.plot(n,buf2,color ='b')

  ax2.set_xlabel('angle')
  ax2.set_ylabel('magnitude')


  plt.show()
#   return buf1,buf2

rotate_me(A,n)
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. When answering a question that already has a few answers, please be sure to add some additional insight into why the response you're providing is substantive and not simply echoing what's already been vetted by the original poster. This is especially important in "code-only" answers such as the one you've provided.